# Internal microphone not detected and hence not working

Tags: dell, alsa, microphone, realtek, 19.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10, wiping Windows 10, and my internal microphone isn't working. I tried installing Pulse Audio, alsamixer and there there is no internal mic being detected.

[image: Input settings screenshot]

However, when I connect a headphone with a mic, it works fine. I also tried to add few combinations under `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file, following a few blogs, unsuccessfully.

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel

options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

I tried things from the below link as well but unfortunately didn't work

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_not_detected_by_PulseAudio

Under alsamixer the card is HDA Intel PCH and Chip is Realtek ALC3204

Note: My Laptop config is like this

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmKfI.png)

Any and all kind of help is appreciated.

PS: I am a newbie, who has just started to learn and my first step was to install the OS.

**Edit** - I have updated to the stable version of 19.10, updated all the possible updates and tried the above-mentioned steps. Unfortunately, my internal mic is still not being detected and as a result unable to use.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 gets released later this week, and currently is still ubuntu+1 (development release) and off-topic on this site.  It is supported via IRC or Ubuntu Forums, but not on this site until after officially released - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you install all available updates in Ubuntu 19.10 and still have this problem, then I recommend you **[edit]** this question to clarify that and also to provide details about how the problem has changed (if it has). Your edit will automatically get the question considered for possible reopening.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I tried after the updates, unfortunately i have the same result

Comment: Same problem here. `arecord -l` shows `ALC3254 Analog` device, but the Input as that of OP. `dmesg | grep ALC3254
[    4.067723] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC3254: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
` Also here seems to be similar question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195343/dell-g3-3590-microphone-not-working

Comment: I have a Dell laptop with a ALC3204 running fedora 31, kernel 5.4.8. Installing packages alsa-ucm and alsa-firmware fixed audio input for me. I'm using sof-audio-pci driver. Not sure how this translates to Ubuntu land

Comment: I have no sound either and I am on Ubuntu 19.10. I really hope there is a fix soon!

Comment: @Clivest which version of alsa-firmware?

Comment: @lf_araujo Fedora packages alsa-firmware-1.2.1-6.fc31.noarch (i.e. 1.2.1) and alsa-ucm-1.2.2-2.fc31.noarch (i.e. 1.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Vostro 5490 from dell that has the acl 3204 chipset, the only way I managed to solve the microphone problem was to install the kernel `linux-image-5.0.0-1060-oem-osp1`

Comment: Johnatan. Where did you get the linux-image-5.0.0-1060-oem-osp1 kernel? I need linux-image-5.0.0-1034-oem-osp1 in order to get everything ok on my dell Latitud 3410. Thanx
Leo