# Dell G3 3590 microphone not working

Tags: sound, dell, alsa, microphone

I'm having problems with the internal microphone of my dell G3 for since I installed Linux (first with in Manjaro, and now the same problem in Ubuntu).

Right now: basically the sound is working fine, everything seems ok (despite the fact that there is no detection of input device) 
[image: settings->sound]

In alsamixer also seem ok with one exception, there is no internal microphone detected 
[image: alsamixer]

but there is this two input source in the right at alsamixer, I can switch both between "Headset Mic" and "Headphone Mic" which dos not affect anything at first when I switch between then.

I tried to use audacity to test the mic and see if I could get any sound at all, I can control this options of mic

[image: audacity]

If I select any of the `HDA Intel PCH: ALC3254 Analog` I get no sound, and if I select any of the `Alt Analog` I get a static noise, what is curious about it is that in the DELL's website in windows drivers you can find this "Realtek ALC3254 High Definition Audio Codec Driver".

At this point I noticed another thing, if I connect a headset things start to change, in the settings->sound I got two options

[image: settings-sound after plug in a headset]

If I select in the input device "Headset Microphone - built-in Audio" everything works normally, but if I select "Microphone - Built-in Audio" then everything just mute, I can't hear anything from the computer and audacity changes too, now only the "Alt Analog" inputs got available, and all of them just output static.

A thing that I notice is that in dell's website there is a mention that this laptop has two microphone input,

My guess is: Somehow the way that they assemble these two microphones kinda bug everything.

Do you have any ideas how can I solve it?

edit1: I tried update the bios, but no success. A curious thing that i notice in the Pulse Audio Volume Control->Input Devices there is a "Monitor of Build-in Audio Analog Stereo" which is playing the same thing that the Volume Control->Output Devices "Speakers".
[image] [image]

quick update 06/01/20
i try call the dell technical services and they basically said that once you buy a product with a operational system, they cannot provide you ANY support to other operational system even though they have all that is needed to.
i have a friend who bought a G3 with Ubuntu standard, and i'll try to "pirate" a copy of dell recovery tools for Ubuntu, from him service tag and i'll update you guys here.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what release of Ubuntu, but most releases primarily use PulseAudio, so have you tried playing there.

Comment: @guiverc i'm using ubuntu 19.10. i follow this steps https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/audio/pulseaudio/docs/install-pulseaudio and still get the same result. If i remember correctly in Manjaro i was using pulseaudio and get the same result as well.

Comment: I wasn't meaning you to install anything; Pulse Audio is already installed on Ubuntu 19.10.  Ubuntu 19.10 is a main release of Ubuntu, not an Ubuntu Core IoT appliance (with no desktop, no sound by default as not all appliances have sound and are usually headless thus it requires installation).  Your system had it installed already, and I'd use that version.  Thus I'd recommend removing the PulseAudio snap if you installed it. I was suggesting `pavucontrol` which is pre-installed on your system (ie. pulse audio volume control); my first 'goto' for any sound issue in modern audio.

Comment: If you need sophisticated audio in Ubuntu, Ubuntu Studio would be my *goto* for details; including their documentation.   Thank you for looking for help in documentation though :)

Comment: Nothing works unfortuly. @guiverc i will try Ubuntu Studio, thanks for the suggestion and the attention. Cheers.

Comment: I have the same issue with Dell Inspiron 7590. Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: @КристиянКацаров I given up. Just install windows and never buy a Dell again.

Comment: I've the same problem but I'm using Lenovo [My question is here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240596/microphone-not-working-neither-built-in-nor-plugged-just-noise-or-muted-lenov)

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS WHAT WORKED FOR ME,

DELL G3 3590 is certified in Ubuntu 18.04 ONLY. It's very weird that later versions break functionality in this laptop.

The Dell G3 3590 version I have is the revised one (2019 version) but I guess the older 3590 version should work as well.

Do not install Ubuntu 20.04 or other version except 18.04 on this notebook.

I just did a Fresh install and at first sound wasn't working, then a Automatic Update at first boot (it's common when fresh install to get an update) added the sound and microphone working. If not, just `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Then I added additional drivers for Nvidia and is working nice.

***UPDATE***
On February aprox. a new version of ubuntu was released (18.04.4) and it has an optional upgrade called HWE that contains newer kernel and stuff. My solution worked but in some point, audio from the headphone jack was missing.

running `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` solved this issue. So I have fresh install ubuntu 18.04.4, updated it and finally updated to HWE and have all sound working! internal and external as well.

WHAT A RIDE!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to achieve static noise while recording, you were close to victory. You just had to change the sampling rate using console commands.

Comment: dude i wast so much time trying to solve it that i kinda give up of everything. maybe some day i'll try to do again.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The only solution I found was to reinstall the system with dell's ISO.

I know it's not the best solution. But I really didn't find another one.

> Dell Linux Recovery Image
>  Create Linux installation media for your
>   Dell device.
>  Need to install or reinstall Linux on you Dell
>   system?
>  Download a Dell ISO recovery image file and use the Dell
>   OS Recovery Tool to create a bootable USB drive.
>
> What you will need
>
> - The Service Tag or product ID of the device you need a recovery image for.
> - A hard drive or removable media with [access rights](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/SLN302281) and at least 8GB of [available data storage space](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/SLN302280) for the download.
> - A blank USB drive with at least 8GB of space to create the installation media.
> - [Preview the instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln301761/how-to-use-the-dell-hosted-recovery-image-of-linux?lang=en) before you begin.

[Reference](https://www.dell.com/support/home/br/pt/brbsdt1/drivers/osiso/linux)

Comment: interesting, i've didnt found this site before. I'll try to get some time thoses days and try it. Right now i'm really busy in work and i cannot afford to lose any time with it. But thanks for your help :)