# Microphone not working, neither built-in nor plugged, just noise or muted. Lenovo ideapad 320s 20.04

Tags: sound, lenovo, 20.04, microphone

I came from Manjaro. I had lot of issues regarding Arch lack of stability and I'm a newbie Linux user. So, I came back to Ubuntu user-friendly with Debian stability.

Sadly one of Manjaro's issues is still present, the microphone is not working. I can't use it in Skype nor Firefox nor Chomium. If I use the built-in microphone there is only a bit of noise, if I plug the headphones (with microphone) just silent, I can hear everything but no body in the video-call can hear me.

Also, one day in the settings menu, the microphone setting became crazy switching back and forth between internal and external microphone.

I know the microphone works perfectly well because I have no issues in Windows.

Comment: Muting right microphone using pavucontrol doesn't fix anything.

Comment: I'll try hdajackretask

Comment: It's working now but only using the external one